# Electric currents due to the Coriolis force?

Tags: electromagnetism, reference-frames, superconductivity, coriolis-effect

In the [Compton generator experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compton_generator) one uses a hollow glass tube filled with water. When this is flipped over, the water gains a small velocity of the order of 0.1 mm/s for a 1 m radius tube, due to the Earth's rotation. If we instead use a superconducting wire, then the current generated after flipping over the wire should be very large. Yet, no such effects seem to exist for electric currents. Why not?

Comment: Do you have a source for an experiment that was performed to test this? You give the impression that you know of such an experiment, and that it produced a null result. I surmise your reasoning is as follows: if the population of electrons in a superconductor is regarded as a superfluid then one would expect that fluid to behave like the fluid in a Compton generator setup.

Answer (score 1):

Without loss of generality, the original Compton generator can be placed on earth's rotational north pole. After a while the fluid in the ring has accelerated (due to viscosity and wall friction) to catch up with the inner walls of the ring and hence rotates, together with the ring, with the angular velocity of the earth. If the ring gets quickly turned over, the fluid keeps rotating in the original sense relative to the ring, while the ring now rotates in the opposite sense. See also [this](https://thatsmaths.com/2020/02/13/a-ring-of-water-shows-the-earths-spin/) presentation.

Given that, the experiment is almost equivalent (well, of course, except for some differences in wall pressure due to centripetal forces) to one where the ring (and the contained fluid) is initially at rest, and then is abruptly set into rotation. It takes some time for the fluid to achieve a new equilibrium relative to the ring, due to viscosity and wall friction. In the meantime this angular velocity difference between fluid and ring/walls can be measured.

Thus the original question can be considered equivalent to the question, whether an initially resting superconducting ring, that is set into a constant rotational motion, will also develop a constant rotational supercurrent. Or alternatively: if there was already a supercurrent in the superconductor at rest, whether the supercurrent changes due to setting the superconductor in rotational motion.

However, the electrons that make up a supercurrent are bound as Cooper pairs and the Cooper pairs are bound to the superconductor's lattice. Hence, the supercurrent is only defined by the geometric relation between the Cooper pairs and the lattice. If the rotational state of the superconductor is changed, the lattice starts rotating. Then there are two possible cases:

1. either the Cooper pairs are able to faithfully follow the rotational acceleration because the energy change is below the threshold that is required to break up the interaction between Cooper pairs and the lattice (I guess thats the first excitation energy of the bosonic Cooper pair spectrum); consequentially the supercurrent does not change in this case, because the Cooper pairs keep having no relative rotation with respect to the SC ring
2. or the change in rotational energy is so high as to break up the Cooper pair/lattice interaction and superconductivity breaks down; thus, any existing supercurrent also breaks down in this case